# wp-nav menu with custom walker , how to remove a tag if it has any submenu

Tags: menus, navigation

i want to do wp_nav_menu custom walker ? can i convert wordpress menu this html

if it has any submenu remove a tag from list item for example below galleries item

I tried to leave empty link . but it did not work. 'a href="#"> completely must remove from galleries item

I share at least 10 forums and groups. I could not find the solution
i really appreciate it your answers

```
    <ul id="menu-mainmenu" class="top-menu"><li  class=" normal-menu"><a href="http://www.event282.com/"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
    <li  class=" menu-item-has-children "><span class="title"><a href="http://www.event282.com/?page_id=65"><span>GALERRIES</span></span></i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.event282.com/?galeri_kategorisi=hamilelik-fotograflari"><span>GALLERY1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.event282.com/?galeri_kategorisi=dugun-fotograflari"><span>GALLERY2</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.event282.com/?galeri_kategorisi=dugun-cekimleri"><span>GALLERY3</span></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="normal-menu"><a href="http://www.event282.com/?page_id=60"><span>BIO</span></a></li>
     <li  class=" normal-menu"><a href="http://www.event282.com/?page_id=48"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: use this one but need your logic where have change :
https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Please try to clarify, and post any PHP you have-- generated HTML is next to useless.

Comment: i want to do wp nav menu with custom walker